# How can I prepare this natural gas line so I can connect a grill?

Tags: gas

When we moved into our new house the builder mentioned there was a gas line coming out of the house. I'd like to use this to  connect a grill. However, looking at the gas pipe I don't see any kind of valve to shut off the gas (attached image).
Would I be able to just pop off the cap and connect the grill, or am I missing any other parts?
[image]

Comment: Is there a shutoff for this anywhere inside the house?

Comment: Not that I can tell...

Comment: Not sure what code says, but if it were me I'd have a valve inside and outside. The valve inside would allow me to control the gas, so I'd turn it on when using the grill, and off when not.  The valve outside would be used in case of emergency, for quick gas shut off.  Having a gas line that anybody could turn on/off, seems a bit dangerous to me.

Comment: For grills in my area I don't think I have ever seen inside shut-offs.  Also most of the time the gas lines for gas lights or grills never enter the house.

Answer (score 2):

You would first turn off the gas at the meter. Then, if this pipe extending from the wall is indeed a gas line, you would take off the cap, clean the threads well, install suitable thread sealer made specifically for gas lines and install an appropriate gas shutoff valve. Install the grill gas connection down flow from this new valve using adapter fittings if necessary.

Then in case you ever need to disconnect the grill for winter, cleaning, replacement, moving or whatever else you can shut off this added valve without having to turn off all the gas in the house.

If you ever do disconnect the grill from the valve it would be necessary to cap off the open valve end for safety sake --- just in case someone comes along and accidentally turns on the valve.

Comment: Don't forget the low pressure regulator if the primary regulator is higher that the grill requires.

Comment: Also check with the grill specs to see if venturi vent needs to be changed for natural gas from propane.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be buying a new grill so I would just get the natural gas one instead of LP.

Comment: If you're installing the valve outside, you might want to consider a valve that can be locked in the off position via a padlock. Don't think I'd want a gas valve on the outside of my house, that anybody could actuate.